# Type error when trying to access the dict value

Tags: python, dictionary

i have a dict

```
  d1={'a':['in-gaap','inr',0,1],'b':['in-gaap','inr',0,2],'c':['in-ca','share',0,4],'n1':['','','','aaa']}
    d2={'d':['in-gaap','inr',0,'a+b'],'e':['in-gaap','inr',0,'y+t']}
    for k in d2.iterkeys():
        a=re.findall('\w+',d2[k][3])
        x2=dict([(x,d1.get(x,0)[3])for x in a]) # here its showing Type:error int obj not subscriptable
        d1[k]=[d2[k][0],d2[k][1],d2[k][2],eval(d2[k][3],x2)]
```

'a' is a list dynamically created it splits d[k][3] and stores it in "a"
d[k][3] contains in first iteration a=['a','b'] and in second iteration a=['y','t']
Actually i am comparing list "a" keys with dict "d1" keys if key is their it takes that value or it assigns default value,upto this its working fine.
But when i try to create dict by  comparing list "a" with dict "d1" ,by using code
    x2=dict([(x,d1.get(x,0)[3])for x in a])

it shows Type:error int object not subsricptable. i dono y but d2[k][3] has value but it showing error.

Comment: d1.get(x,0)[3] problem is here get method is not returning list.. why you are getting [3] index of int where default value is 0 ?

Comment: @akhter wahab if u see dict "d1" their i stored values as list d1={ 'a':['in-gaap','inr',0,1]....} i need to get "1" which is at index "3"  so i am using d.get(x,0)[3],default value will be assigned if value is balnk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d1.get(x,0)[3]`. This is your problem. If `x` isn't in `d1`, `d1.get(x,0)` returns `0`. And `0[3]` is a TypeError.

Replace the problem line with these lines, and it should work, assuming I read your intent correctly:

```
values = [d1[x][3] if x in d1 else 0 for x in a]
x2 = dict(zip(a, values))
```

This is slightly easier to read too.

Comment: Thanks@aquavitae,i got the root cause of my problem can u say how can i modify this code

Comment: Thanks@aquavitae, post as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
d1={'a':['in-gaap','inr',0,1],'b':['in-gaap','inr',0,2],'c':['in-ca','share',0,4],'n1':['','','','aaa']}
d2={'d':['in-gaap','inr',0,'a+b'],'e':['in-gaap','inr',0,'y+t']}
for k in d2.iterkeys():
    a=re.findall('\w+',d2[k][3])
    print a
    for x in a:
        print 'x is :',x # at first iteration **x=='y'** so **d1.get(x,0)** will return **0** so you can't get **d1.get(x,0)[3]**
        print d1.get(x,0)
```

output

```
['y', 't']
x is : y
0
x is : t
0
['a', 'b']
x is : a
['in-gaap', 'inr', 0, 1]
x is : b
['in-gaap', 'inr', 0, 2]
```